# ASMX Web Service deployment issue on IIS7 - Win7

Tags: soap, windows-7, iis-7, asmx

I'm getting the following error when trying the basic HellowWorld SOAP Web Service. It works fine when debugging from Visual Studio. Any ideas?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file &#39;C:\windows\TEMP\evamkhpw.0.cs&#39; could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified

   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturn.GetInitializers(LogicalMethodInfo[] methodInfos)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by installing IIS6 compatibility on my machine.